# C++11: Nonmember rbegin()/rend() Functions

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, c++11

Since the nonmember `begin()` and `end()` functions were added for standard contains in the C++11 revision, why have the nonmember versions of the `rbegin()` and `rend()` functions not been added as well? I feel silly after beginning to use the nonmember versions of `begin()` and `end()`, only to find that I now have to toggle between the using the member and nonmember function calls. (I realize that it would be trivial to roll my own nonmember versions of `rbegin()` and `rend()`, but I'm wondering why this wasn't added to the standard).

Thanks for your input.

Comment: I remember something being said about this in one of the presentations at [Going Native 2012](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/GoingNative-2012).  It seems these functions were simply forgotten and may (will?) be added in the standard at a later point.

Comment: The non-member `begin()` and `end()` functions are used by the new form of `for` statement added to C++11. The other functions are not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can construct reversed range by manually using `std::reverse_iterator` on the results of `std::begin` and `std::end`.

Oddly, there is not a standard factory function for `reverse_iterator`. If there were, it would probably look like this:

```
template< typename iter >
std::reverse_iterator< iter > reverse( iter i )
    { return { i }; }
```

Armed with this, you can do

```
std::sort( reverse( std::end( my_array ) ), reverse( std::begin( my_array ) ) );
```

This example saves the trouble of specifying the `std::greater` comparator, but the `reverse_iterator` conceivably could adversely affect performance if the compiler can't remove the added complexity from inner loops.

Answer (score 7):

For people who see this later, nonmember `rbegin()` and `rend()` are already in C++14.

Comment: Ha! That's what I expect. Because I cannot see the overhead of adding rbegin() based on begin() nonmember function. Embrace C++ 14!